# More than one Omnifaces socket on a single page

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

Is it possible to use multiple Omnifaces sockets with different users on a single page?

It seems to me, that only one socket can be opened on a single page.
If I define two sockets, only one seems to work.

Example of the code I used:

```
<h:form>
    <o:socket channel="taskChannel" onclose="socketErrorHandler"  user="user1">
        <p:ajax event="update" ignoreAutoUpdate="true" global="false" update="component1/>
    </o:socket>
</h:form>

<h:form>
    <o:socket channel="taskChannel" onclose="socketErrorHandler" user="user2">
        <p:ajax event="update" ignoreAutoUpdate="true" global="false" update="component2/>
    </o:socket>
</h:form>
```